# System becomes unresponsive due to kernel oops (IP: dev_queue_xmit+0x256/0x3f4)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, netlink, acpi

Linux system is consistently getting unresponsive with below serial console output. The similar serial console output is observed every time the issue is occurred.

Steps to reproduce this issue are unknown as of now. But, this issue is not observed when all parameters related to acpi are disabled from BIOS.

I am newbie to debugging kernel oops. Please let me know what could be the problem and how can I resolve this issue. Any pointer or help will be very important.

Stack trace is as,

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)
IP: [<c06fbcdd>] dev_queue_xmit+0x256/0x3f4
*pdpt = 000000002ecb3001 *pde = 000000012974c067 
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0/broadcast
Modules linked in: tun nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink bluetooth rfkill ts_kmp xt_string 8021q garp nf_nat_pptp nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_]

Pid: 14113, comm: snort Not tainted 2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE #1 To be filled by O.E.M./To Be Filled By O.E.M.
EIP: 0060:[<c06fbcdd>] EFLAGS: 00210202 CPU: 1
EIP is at dev_queue_xmit+0x256/0x3f4
EAX: f6922000 EBX: f6bf5a80 ECX: ed524140 EDX: f6123380
ESI: f6248000 EDI: 00000000 EBP: eef7dbf0 ESP: eef7dbdc
 DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Process snort (pid: 14113, ti=eef7c000 task=eef28cc0 task.ti=eef7c000)
Stack:
 eef7dbec f6923300 f6bf5a80 ef48f360 ed524108 eef7dc14 c0722500 001aa8b4
<0> 00000000 ef48f350 ef48f300 00000028 f6bf5a80 001aa8b4 eef7dc20 c0722591
<0> f6bf5a80 eef7dc2c c0722819 f0fc4800 eef7dc34 c07216d5 eef7dc4c c0713b12
Call Trace:
 [<c0722500>] ? ip_finish_output2+0x18e/0x1c6
 [<c0722591>] ? ip_finish_output+0x59/0x5c
 [<c0722819>] ? ip_output+0x74/0x79
 [<c07216d5>] ? dst_output+0x9/0xb
 [<c0713b12>] ? nf_reinject+0xa3/0xe6
 [<f80ab427>] ? nfqnl_recv_verdict+0x1cf/0x1e0 [nfnetlink_queue]
 [<f7e6b1ab>] ? nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x118/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<f7e6b0b9>] ? nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x26/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0711903>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x72/0x221
 [<f7e6b093>] ? nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x0/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0711130>] ? netlink_rcv_skb+0x30/0x76
 [<f7e6b08c>] ? nfnetlink_rcv+0x1b/0x22 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0710f6f>] ? netlink_unicast+0xbe/0x119
 [<c0711aa5>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x214/0x221
 [<c06edfad>] ? __sock_sendmsg+0x45/0x4e
 [<c06ee254>] ? sock_sendmsg+0x93/0xa7
 [<c0442bfc>] ? irq_exit+0x39/0x5c
 [<c0409c05>] ? do_IRQ+0x86/0x9a
 [<c0408df0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
 [<c06f625f>] ? verify_iovec+0x57/0x6c
 [<c06ee676>] ? sys_sendmsg+0x187/0x1eb
 [<c06ee4c2>] ? sockfd_lookup_light+0x16/0x43
 [<c06ee4aa>] ? fput_light+0xc/0xe
 [<c06ef6d7>] ? sys_recvfrom+0x102/0x121
 [<c06fbf04>] ? dev_kfree_skb_any+0x27/0x32
 [<f88c3dfb>] ? e1000_put_txbuf+0x50/0x65 [e1000e]
 [<f88c3ee8>] ? e1000_clean_tx_irq+0xa7/0x1dc [e1000e]
 [<c05a6680>] ? might_fault+0x19/0x1b
 [<c05a68eb>] ? copy_to_user+0x2f/0x108
 [<c05a6680>] ? might_fault+0x19/0x1b
 [<c06efe80>] ? sys_socketcall+0x15e/0x1a5
 [<c040ff01>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xa5/0xb8
 [<c0782bdc>] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
 [<c0780000>] ? acpi_processor_add+0x1f/0x74b
Code: 57 0c 66 89 83 80 00 00 00 8b 96 00 02 00 00 0f b7 c0 c1 e0 07 01 d0 89 45 f0 8b 78 04 66 8b 43 7e 80 e4 cf 80 cc 20 66 89 43 7e <83> 3f  
EIP: [<c06fbcdd>] dev_queue_xmit+0x256/0x3f4 SS:ESP 0068:eef7dbdc
CR2: 0000000000000000
---[ end trace 5e9db4f99c9e9021 ]---

Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Message from syslogd@machine Pid: 14113, comm: snort Tainted: G      D    2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE #1
Call Trace:
 [<c0780b4f>] ? printk+0xf/0x18
 [<c0780a8d>] panic+0x39/0xec
 [<c0783c90>] oops_end+0x92/0xa1
 [<c04261c1>] no_context+0x13e/0x148
 [<c04262b7>] __bad_area_nosemaphore+0xec/0xf4
 [<c0784e87>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x2fa
 [<c04262cc>] bad_area_nosemaphore+0xd/0x10
 [<c078501b>] do_page_fault+0x194/0x2fa
 [<c0784e87>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x2fa
 [<c07832df>] error_code+0x73/0x78
 [<c06fbcdd>] ? dev_queue_xmit+0x256/0x3f4
 [<c0722500>] ip_finish_output2+0x18e/0x1c6
 [<c0722591>] ip_finish_output+0x59/0x5c
 [<c0722819>] ip_output+0x74/0x79
 [<c07216d5>] dst_output+0x9/0xb
 [<c0713b12>] nf_reinject+0xa3/0xe6
 [<f80ab427>] nfqnl_recv_verdict+0x1cf/0x1e0 [nfnetlink_queue]
 [<f7e6b1ab>] nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x118/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<f7e6b0b9>] ? nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x26/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0711903>] ? netlink_sendmsg+0x72/0x221
 [<f7e6b093>] ? nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x0/0x149 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0711130>] netlink_rcv_skb+0x30/0x76
 [<f7e6b08c>] nfnetlink_rcv+0x1b/0x22 [nfnetlink]
 [<c0710f6f>] netlink_unicast+0xbe/0x119
 [<c0711aa5>] netlink_sendmsg+0x214/0x221
 [<c06edfad>] __sock_sendmsg+0x45/0x4e
 [<c06ee254>] sock_sendmsg+0x93/0xa7
 [<c0442bfc>] ? irq_exit+0x39/0x5c
 [<c0409c05>] ? do_IRQ+0x86/0x9a
 [<c0408df0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
 [<c06f625f>] ? verify_iovec+0x57/0x6c
 [<c06ee676>] sys_sendmsg+0x187/0x1eb
 [<c06ee4c2>] ? sockfd_lookup_light+0x16/0x43
 [<c06ee4aa>] ? fput_light+0xc/0xe
 [<c06ef6d7>] ? sys_recvfrom+0x102/0x121
 [<c06fbf04>] ? dev_kfree_skb_any+0x27/0x32
 [<f88c3dfb>] ? e1000_put_txbuf+0x50/0x65 [e1000e]
 [<f88c3ee8>] ? e1000_clean_tx_irq+0xa7/0x1dc [e1000e]
 [<c05a6680>] ? might_fault+0x19/0x1b
 [<c05a68eb>] ? copy_to_user+0x2f/0x108
 [<c05a6680>] ? might_fault+0x19/0x1b
 [<c06efe80>] sys_socketcall+0x15e/0x1a5
 [<c040ff01>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xa5/0xb8
 [<c0782bdc>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
 [<c0780000>] ? acpi_processor_add+0x1f/0x74b
```

Comment: Refer [Documentation/oops-tracing.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt?id=HEAD). Looks like you are running FC13 with a pretty old version of the kernel. Its best if you considering upgrading.

Comment: Hi askb,Thank you for the referance, but I have to continue with the FC13 for now. At the max I can patch the kernel, so I am looking for if there is any patch which can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the kernel to 2.6.39 and e1000e driver on fedora13. This resolved this issue. Answering as it might help others.(even after long time. Sorry for that.)